# regex-urlfilter syntax with Apache Nutch

Tags: java, regex, apache, nutch

I want to filter the url in format like: https://www.abcd.com/def/* which means anything after the def/ is ok as long as the domain is www.abcd.com and /def/ is required , but after spending a lot of time I still can't figure out how to write the correct regular expression.

Comment: Next time please make sure to include anything you've tried in your post, to demonstrate that you've made an effort. Having shown effort to solve it yourself first, you'll get a much better response from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
 +^https://www.abcd.com/def/(.*)
#(skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.)
 -^https://www.abcd.com/def/[?*!@=]
# skip URLs with slash-delimited segment that repeats 3+ times, to break loops
 -^https://www.abcd.com/def/.*(/[^/]+)/[^/]+\1/[^/]+\1/
#comment "accept everything else"   
#+.
```